# How to change style code behind windows phone app 8.1 RT

Tags: windows-runtime, textblock

I have a style in App.xaml like below

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Styletext">
<Setter Property="Fontsize" Value="13"/></Style>
```

And in the mainpage.xaml. I have

`<TextBlock Content="ABC" Style={StaticResource Styletext/>`

And 2 Button Aa-,Aa+ To Up size for that textblock. So Question is: How I can get Value from Property"Fontsize" and + or - it and Modify Style to Assign for TextBlock. Tks All

Comment: You could do this (changing the style, access via container resources), but it won't work: it's _static_resource for a reason :) WPF has DynamicResource for this, but it's not in WinRT or Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the style in static resource. For your requirement, you can considering setting the style of TextBlock in code behind.

For example:

```
        var dynamicStyle = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Style();

        var targetType = typeof(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock);

        dynamicStyle.TargetType = targetType;

        dynamicStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, text01.FontSize + 1));

        text01.Style = dynamicStyle;
```

Comment: OK agree with dynamic resource, but how can i get value "size" in old style before

Comment: very simple, text01.FontSize + 1, I've revised the code in my reply